# css cannot be loaded for different rewrite rules htacess

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two different rewrite rules for the requested url like

(1)
`mysite/profile.php?u=username` and rewrite to `mysite/username`

(2)
`mysite/profile.php?u=username&s=photos` rewrite to `mysite/username/photos`

my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mysite/
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ profile.php?u=$1&s=$2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mysite/
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ profile.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

my html head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/core.main.css">
```

when i request something like `mysite/jenny`, the css loaded without any issue, however, when i request `mysite/jennny/photos`, the page is found but without any css rendering?

what would be the issue,from similar question, I tried to modify the path for including the css, like `href="/css/core.main.css"`, but without success

Comment: What is the filepath on the server, starting from server root, to the css file?

Comment: Try to use absolute path for css file? E.g. http://yoursite.com/css/your_css.css

Comment: @nevermind, I'm testing on my local server, which in my case, is http://localhost:8888/mysite/ , so should I write it like http://localhost:8888/mysite/css/core.main.css?

Comment: The relative path to your CSS will be completed to a different URL for `/username` and `/username/photos` … and only one of them is correct. Using paths beginning with a leading slash to refer to the domain root is an easy solution to that.

Comment: @CBroe what do you mean, can you give me an example, thank you

Comment: `/css/core.main.css` (or whatever the correct path to your CSS is from the root.)